# Dual Monitor on Raspberry Pi4 running Ubuntu 23.1 and KDE Plasma

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, qt, desktop

I have a Pi4 which refuses to display two monitors using Ubuntu 23.10 and KDE Plasma
The same Pi shows the 2 monitors using Ubuntu Mate Desktop.

I am switching to KDE because I want to use PyQt5 not GTK for some home made apps.

I have searched high and low and found two possible solutions to put into the /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt file.

**Solution One**

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
config_hdmi_boost:0=3
config_hdmi_boost:1=3
```

**Solution Two**

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
disable_overscan=1
max_framebuffers=2
```

Neither work.
I have updated the eeprom to the latest.
here is the output of xrandr -q

```
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      0.00*
```

Any ideas welcome